# Hexadecimals in haskell

Tags: haskell, hex

I am wondering why when you define a hexadecimal and then use the formula 
"ord x - ord 'a' +10" Why is the +10 used? What would it give you if this +10 was not used?

Comment: The hexadecimal digit `a` is 10.

Comment: Please consider using `Data.Char.digitToInt` - that also works for upper case hex digits! Unless you want 'A' to represent -22, of course, in which case carry on :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the `+ 10`, you'd map the letters a to f to the value 0 to 5, instead of 10 to 15.

Answer (score 2):

`ord x - (ord 'a')` gives you *rank* of the char `'a'` being 0, `'b'` 1 etc ...
to convert this *rank* to the hexa value you need to add 10, so `a` => 10, `b` => 11 etc ..

You want `'a'` to be 10 because after 9 (coded as `'9'`) comes 10 (encoded as `'a'`).